Trimble R2 connection to QField on Android device
I have a problem connecting Trimble R2 to QField. However, I can see some position information on QField as I connect Trimble R2 using a mock location provided by the Mobile Manager.
If I connect Trimble R2 via Bluetooth in QField (bypassing the mock location provided by Mobile Manager), no position information is given despite established connection between the Android phone and GNSS receiver.
Is there a way to connect a Trimble R2 directly to QField?
